# "Put your hand under my thigh" clarification

Tags: torah-study

Genesis 24:2

> And Abraham said to his slave, the oldest in his house, the one who
> ruled in all that was to him. Please put your hand under my thigh.

What does "under my thigh" means? Does it mean allowing his servant's hand to be sat on, or between the inner thighs?